# Skrollr responding to H1 tag and not container tag

Tags: html, css, skrollr

I have created a simple page to experiment with Skrollr using it in relative mode. I have 2 sections set up, the first section has an  tag in it, the 2nd section has a

tag in it. The first section is supposed to fade out when the bottom of the first section is at the top of the viewport. But instead of using that section, it's using the  tag to trigger the animations.

```
<section id='burger'>
            <div class='background' data-top="opacity:1" data-top-bottom="opacity:0" data-anchor-target="#burger">
                    <h1>Welcome to the page!</h1>
            </div>
        </section>
```

The 2nd section has a background div on it as well, and that animation should be the image of the 
plane starts off 100px at the top, 0px at the center and -100px at the bottom. The image just seems to sit -100px where it should at all times.

```
 <section id='plane'>
            <div class='background' data-top="background-position: 50% 100px;" data-center="background-position: 50% 0px;" data-bottom="background-position: 50% -100px;" data-anchor-target="#plane">
                <p>Cras nulla odio, fringilla nec libero in, tristique rutrum elit. Phasellus ut tellus non metus pellentesque lacinia at eget tellus. Sed dapibus turpis eu rhoncus lacinia. Mauris ornare arcu et justo facilisis iaculis. Nam ultricies accumsan lacinia. Morbi sit amet nisi vitae turpis feugiat elementum. Phasellus tempor porta arcu non semper. Quisque vitae urna sed mi scelerisque tincidunt. Mauris nulla odio, tempus sit amet fermentum ac, egestas in lacus. Aliquam suscipit velit enim, ac pharetra magna gravida sit amet. In eu libero rhoncus purus tincidunt commodo a venenatis purus. Sed a nibh sed mauris consequat blandit. Morbi ut faucibus ante. In nunc arcu, sodales vel molestie sit amet, mollis quis urna. Aenean pretium facilisis erat. </p>
            </div>
        </section>
```

css:

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
}

h1{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

section{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}


.background{
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#burger{
}

#burger .background{
    background-image: url('../img/burger.jpg');
    border: 3px solid green;
}

#plane .background{
    background-image: url('../img/plane.jpg');
}
```

I'm sure I'm over looking something obvious.. but I can't seem to figure out what it might be.
I uploaded a simple date to demo what I am talking about.
Thanks for the help in advance!

[demo link](http://gdovindesigns.com/skrollr/)

Comment: Is it an issue with your background-position: 50% 100px; on the inline style? I removed that and it seems to do what you want but i am not 100% clear on that?

Comment: But with out that, how will skrollr work? I was under the impression that is attributes that skrollr was using...?

Comment: I am not familiar with Skrollr so i might be off base here but when i removed it via inspect elements i did see the scrolling "paralax" effect i assume that is what skrollr is doing a paralax effext?

Comment: ahh ok.. yes that effect i working.. but the image of the plane should be slightly moving up and down depending how which way you are scrolling, as well as the top image still isn't working correctly. Thanks for looking into this for me though!

Answer (score 2):

Skrollr changes the `height` of the body. In the process of calculating everything, it is set to `auto` (which may be bug https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/issues/347) and later to the needed height, which conflicts with your `100%` (it is overridden).

To disable this behavior, set the `forceHeight` options to `false` when initializing skrollr.

Edit: Regarding your comment (jumping of the background) that's actually pretty easy: in your case `data-top` === `data-bottom`, because the section has `height:100%` (the top will be at the top at the same time when the bottom will be at the bottom). What you wanted was `data-bottom-top` and `data-top-bottom`. Also `data-center` is superfluous.

Comment: Thanks Prinzhorn! That solved the h1 opacity issue. But the background image now seems to just jump between the 2 numbers instead of animating. Any idea why that might be? I updated the link so you can see what I mean.